# Framer Motion not animating when mount or unmounting a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, framer-motion

I am using framer motion to animate the custom table rows whenever they are mounted. But its not animating. When I checked web, they specified that AnimatePresence should be a direct parent for motion. And it should have a key value. Still it doesn't work. I am not sure what I am missing. Please advice. Thanks.

```
return (
<>
...some code here
{isExpanded && <AnimatePresence>{renderLinkedAccounts()}</AnimatePresence>}

</>
);

const renderLinkedAccounts = () => linkdedAccounts.map((model, index) => (
    <motion.Tr
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        layout
        key={index}
    >
        <Td><span /></Td>
        <Td data-tooltip={model.getEmailAddress()}>
            {model.getEmailAddress()}
        </Td>
        <Td>
            {userType === 1 ? model.getAccountId() : model.getMailboxKey()}
        </Td>
        <Td>
            {getAccountType()}
        </Td>
        <Td>
            {getAccountStatus()}
        </Td>
        <Td>{getOutINStatus("outgoing")}</Td>
        <Td>{getOutINStatus("incoming")}</Td>
    </motion.Tr>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `AnimatePresence` might not work if it is also conditionally rendered, perhaps try:

```
<AnimatePresence>{isExpanded && renderLinkedAccounts()}</AnimatePresence>
```

If this does not fix it, it could also be possible that `motion.Tr` does not have a transition set for `opacity`. Perhaps try add the property, such as `transition={{ opacity: { duration: 0.2 } }}` to the `motion` component.

Simplified demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-krvyh4?file=src/App.js) (this is uses a simple `tr` instead of the custom `Tr`)

Example:

```
<motion.Tr
  initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
  animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
  exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
  layout
  key={index}
  transition={{
    opacity: { duration: 0.2 },
  }}
>
...
```

Lastly if still not animating, perhaps the custom `Tr` could be checked to see if it has some specific styles that might be preventing the animation from happening.